# Usage, prevalence of “rooster sauce” and “cock sauce”

Tags: slang, dialects, nicknames

**[Sriracha sauce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sriracha_sauce)** is a kind of chili sauce named for Si Racha, Thailand, but in the United States many people call it **“rooster sauce”** or **“cock sauce”** after the prominent rooster logo on a [popular brand](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sriracha_sauce_%28Huy_Fong_Foods%29) of the sauce.

[image]
<sup>Photo by [Memphis CVB](http://www.flickr.com/photos/ilovememphis/)</sup>

Most people I know in the San Francisco Bay Area just call it “Sriracha,” but I occasionally hear the nicknames too. I originally assumed that more serious folk would only use the “rooster sauce” name, with “cock sauce” reserved for jokers and provocateurs* because of the [*double entendre*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cock). As food blogger [Alan Sytsma](http://www.gourmet.com/food/2008/02/sriracha) notes (emphasis added):

> After all, how many condiments have their own nicknames? Ketchup? No. Mustard? Not a chance. But Sriracha? In a nod to its bottle many connoisseurs simply call it **“cock sauce,” a name that is as bawdy and virile as the sauce itself.**

However, I recently heard a man in Green Bay use the “cock sauce” nickname quite matter-of-factly, with none of the usual vocal cues that would indicate irony or innuendo. That got me to wondering just how prevalent those nicknames are – and in particular, how many people use “cock sauce” without sniggering.

How widespread are the “rooster sauce” and “cock sauce” nicknames for Sriracha sauce? Are there any significant examples of English speakers or writers using the latter term in more sober contexts?

---

<sup>* Like me.</sup>

Comment: http://theoatmeal.com/comics/sriracha

Comment: Can confirm I have seen bottles labelled "Cock Sauce" here in New Zealand. It wasn't in the traditional clear bottle with green cap packaging however.

Comment: @MichaelFrank For the same thing, or for something else?

Comment: @MichaelFrank Interesting! I would search for it, but I'm afraid to do a Google image search for “cock sauce” at the office. And I don't think “cock sauce New Zealand” would improve things much.

Comment: @tchrist It tasted similar, and was just as hot.

Comment: @BraddSzonye Afraid to do a Google image search at the office for [hot catsup](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14380947#14380947)? Whyever for? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a New Yorker, I'm use to most people simply referring to it as "Sriracha" (sir-ah-chuh). Pretty much every cooking show and TV chef refers to it thusly.

Occasionally, fans of the stuff will call it "rooster sauce". This is also useful terminology for people who have only tried the stuff a few times in a sushi restaurant or something (they're more likely to remember the rooster on the label, rather than the actual name).

Cock sauce tends to only be used here for the humor of the double entendre.

Unsure of how common the American-styled Sriracha is outside of America, but the rooster/cock terminology can be broken down like so:

"Rooster" is a term that originated in the United States, and it's also common in Australia and New Zealand, which is why the nickname "rooster sauce" is more common than "cock sauce" in these places ("cock" appears to be considered vulgar in at least these 3 countries as well).

"Cock" is more common in European countries, so when referring to the American-styled Sriracha, "cock sauce" would be preferred, and probably cause less snickering.

Comment: This is interesting if true; can you point to any sources that support it?

Comment: @BraddSzonye which part?

Comment: Any of it, but especially the parts that directly answer the question (e.g., that “rooster sauce” is more common in Australia & NZ, “cock sauce” in Europe). Especially because we have somebody who claims to have spotted a bottle of Cock Sauce in NZ.

Comment: @BraddSzonye I'm unsure about NZ. I have a bud that lives in Qld, Australia, and he claims that they use either Sriracha or "rooster sauce" due to theirs also having a rooster on it (and that "cock" has the same slang meaning there for penis). So only primary sources.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a search on Google for cock sauce, currently yields 14,700 results, while a search for rooster sauce yields 128,000 results.

https://www.google.ca/search?q=Sriracha+%2B%22cock+sauce%22
https://www.google.ca/search?q=Sriracha+%2B%22rooster+sauce%22

I'm in Canada, and I've never heard it referred to as cock sauce other than in the context of "have you heard that some people call it cock sauce". And no wonder... the term would be considered very rude around here.